# sort by MySQL special group

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, round-robin

*Table A* shows results that I have by running the following SQL in MySQL.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('marka tv')
```

**Table A**

[image]

*Table B* shows results that I want to get. As you can see the groups are in round-robin order.

**Table B**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question, you want to sort the output so the groups are in a round-robin fashion rather than ordered.  You can do this by enumerating the values within each group and then using that information for sorting:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             (@rn := if(@g = groups, @rn + 1,
                        if(@g := groups, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      FROM table t CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0, @g := '') params
      WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('marka tv')
      ORDER BY groups
     ) t
ORDER BY rn, groups;
```

Comment: exactly as I want, thank you. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: hi, The full-text score less than 7 at the beginning of the sequence of ones I don't want to be. How Can I do this ?

Comment: @user3236432 . . . I'm not sure I fully understand.  You can put a `>` condition on the match, if you are looking for a threshold for that.  Perhaps you should ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a subquery in a derived table to calculate a group number to be sorted at final table:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM
    (SELECT t1.* ,
          (SELECT count(*)
           FROM table t2
           WHERE (t2.title <= t1.title) 
           AND (t1.groups = t2.groups)) AS groupNo
     FROM table t1
     WHERE MATCH (t1.title) AGAINST ('marka tv')
     ) AS f
ORDER BY groupNo, groups
```